# Why isn't my listener attaching?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I originally had the code in `addCommentFormListener` in the `init` method and it worked.  I am trying instead to attach the listener to the relevant elements like so:

```
class CommentsController {
  constructor() {
    this.$addCommentForm = $('.add-comment')
  }

  init() {
    $(".add-comment").each(function() {
        console.log('test2')
        this.addEventListener("submit", this.addCommentFormListener);
    })
  }

  addCommentFormListener() {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('test');
        var image = $(this).closest(".image");
        var imageId = image.find("ul").attr("id");
        var commentContents = $(this).find('input[name="comment-description"]').val();
        console.log(commentContents);
        // var imageObject = Image.all.find(image => image.id => imageId);
    }
}
```

The console logs `test2` the appropriate amount of times, but nothing else happens when I click submit on a given element.  What am I missing?

Separately, it feels strange to me to have the event listener attached on `submit`, rather than for it to already be there and just activated when I hit submit, but that may be just my weak understanding of Javascript listeners.

Edited to add HTML:

```
<form id="add-comment" class="add-comment" data-id="0" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="comment-description">Comment: </label>
        <input type="text" id="comment-description-0" class="user-text" name="comment-description" placeholder="comment">
        <input type="submit" value="(+) add comment">
      </form>
```

Comment: There should be an error, because `e` is undefined.

Comment: @Thomas Good point... but there's not.  I'm not sure what that means.  console is empty except for ten copies of 'test2' as expected

Comment: Adding on to what Thomas said, you would have to add `e` a parameter on your function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the callback passed to `each()`, `this` isn't what you think it is. It is the current element within the iteration, which is why `this.addEventListener` works, but of course then it can't be the `CommentsController` instance at the same time, so the actual callback you're passing is `undefined`.

Since you're using ES6, the easiest way is to use an arrow function:

```
  init() {
    $(".add-comment").each((index, element) => {
        console.log('test2')
        element.addEventListener("submit", this.addCommentFormListener);
    })
  }
```

Also note that within `addCommentFormListener`, `this` will refer to the element that the event was fired on, *not* to your `CommentsController` instance. This works alright currently, but might be confusing if you revisit this code in a month :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything here.  I get why what I originally wrote is using `this` to mean two different things.  Is the `index, element` just to avoid that and rename the first `this`, or is there more to it than that?  What's the point of the `index` parameter?  It doesn't seem used.  With regard to your second point within `addCommentFormListener`, don't I want `this` to refer to the element it was fired on?  Or are you just suggesting I name things better?

Comment: And would I be correct in comparing arrow functions, which are new to me, to lambda functions in Python?  They seem analogous.

Comment: It's not really more or less analogous than regular anonymous `function`s in JavaScript. The main difference between `function` and `=>` is that `=>` will preserve the value of `this` as it was outside the function, whereas with `function` it all depends on the way the function is called. You can think of `() => { ...}` as `(function() { ... }).bind(this)`.